# HTML Edits not showing in browser

Tags: apache2, php7, zendframework

Using a ZF2 based site.

`/var/www/html/app` is root and contains module folders with views and public.

Running `/var/www/html/app/public via`:

```
`php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php`
```

Site loads fine. Within public is my `style.css`. Edits to this show on the browser.

Here is where I'm lost, module `phtml` files ie:

(`/var/www/html/app/user/view/header.phtml`) load fine. But when I make an edit and reload the page, the edits do not show. These files were cloned from git. Permissions are correct. Edit, save file, close, open back up and edits still exist. Just no change on the website.

"Edits made with gedit"

If anyone has any idea, please let me know as I am truly stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you clear your cache in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I have done a couple things with clearing the browser. The css edit show just fine.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, Should I try another?

Comment: Yes you should just so you rule out browser specific issues.

Comment: Well I guess it would be nice if the software center worked. lol. Updating gnome, ill try to get something else installed and let you know.

Comment: So I tried 3 different browsers. All the same. No change.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. Composer issue. Works now.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't a cache issue. Composer added the modules to the wrong directory. Placed the modules within vendor and it works fine now.